# Why am I not getting this divide by zero hardware-detected error in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++

The text given below in blockquote and code sample is from a book called *Programming: Principles and Practice using C++, Chapter 5- Errors (Under the Run-time errors section)*

> Consider:

```
int area(int length, int width) // calculate area of a rectangle
{
return length*width;
}
int framed_area(int x, int y) // calculate area within frame
{
return area(x–2,y–2);
}
int main()
{
int x = –1;
int y = 2;
int z = 4;
// . . .
int area1 = area(x,y);
int area2 = framed_area(1,z);
int area3 = framed_area(y,z);
double ratio = double(area1)/area3; // convert to double to get
// floating-point division
}
```

> We used the variables x, y, z (rather than using the values
> directly as arguments) to make the problems less obvious to the human
> reader and harder for the compiler to detect. However, these calls
> lead to negative values, representing areas, being assigned to area1
> and area2. Should we accept such erroneous results, which violate most
> notions of math and physics? If not, who should detect the errors: the
> caller of area() or the function itself? And how should such errors be
> reported? Before answering those questions, look at the calculation of
> the ratio in the code above. It looks innocent enough. Did you notice
> something wrong with it? If not, look again: area3 will be 0, so that
> double(area1)/area3 divides by zero. **This leads to a
> hardware-detected error that terminates the program with some cryptic
> message relating to hardware. This is the kind of error that you — or
> your users — will have to deal with if you don’t detect and deal
> sensibly with run-time errors.** Most people have low tolerance for
> such “hardware violations” because to anyone not intimately familiar
> with the program all the information provided is “Something went wrong
> somewhere!” That’s insufficient for any constructive action, so we
> feel angry and would like to yell at whoever supplied the program.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not getting that "hardware-detected error" about which the author is talking about in this section. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to test this code and its executing successfully and exiting with Code 0

Comment: It is technically Undefiend Behaviour to divide by zero in C++, but all compilers I know implement `double` according to IEEE 754 standard, which requires division by zero to return `inf` (or `-inf`) and is not undefined at all. You are more likely to see an error with interger division: `area1 / 0`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen So, is it written wrong in the textbook or is it an outdated feature to give an error on double division by zero?

Comment: In practice it's usually not correct for double division.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen _You are more likely to see an error with interger division_ Take it from me, you will :)

Comment: Most likely, the compiler is noticing that `ratio` is dead (never used) so is eliminating the divide as dead code.  In fact it may well notice the entire program is dead (produces no visible output) and delete it.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Well i tried displaying that ratio and got -inf instead of an error. I guess it was undefined behaviour in the end like Yksisarvinen has already said above.

Comment: Well, what I meant is that standard says it's UB. However, it is defined by IEEE754, and you can check if your compiler uses that standard for floats with `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559();`. I can't imagine an architecture that would indeed throw an error on `double/0`, would probably have to be a hardware without floating point math support. The book is wrong implying that it should throw an error, because it won't for most people that run this code.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yeah I get that, I just wondered why it was written like that in the book. I guess this example was intended for a previous version C++ as it would be weird to see C++'s designer being wrong at his own language.