# Getting a debug error using the function error()

Tags: c++

This is a direct follow-up to my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71727416/18692517) I asked recently. I would recommend checking it before reading this.

*The text given below in blockquote and code sample is from a book called Programming: Principles and Practice using C++, Chapter 5- Errors (Under the Run-time errors section)*

> So, let’s tackle the problem of argument errors with area(). We have two obvious
> alternatives:
>
> 1. Let the caller of area() deal with bad arguments.
> 2. Let area() (the called function) deal with bad arguments.

> Let’s try the first alternative (“Let the user beware!”) first. That’s the one we’d
> have to choose if area() was a function in a library where we couldn’t modify it.
> For better or worse, this is the most common approach.
> Protecting the call of area(x, y) in main() is relatively easy:

```
if (x<=0) error("non-positive x");
if (y<=0) error("non-positive y");
int area1 = area(x, y);
```

> Really, the only question is what to do if we find an error. **Here, we have called a
> function error() which we assume will do something sensible. In fact, in
> std_lib_facilities.h we supply an error() function that by default terminates the program
> with a system error message plus the string we passed as an argument to error().
> If you prefer to write out your own error message or take other actions, you catch
> runtime_error (§5.6.2, §7.3, §7.8, §B.2.1).** This approach suffices for most student
> programs and is an example of a style that can be used for more sophisticated
> error handling.

I tried to run the code sample in Visual Studio and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooZqt.png) is what I was greeted to by a window of Microsoft C++ Runtime Library under practice34.exe:

> Debug Error!
> Program:

```
 C:\Users\..\source\repos\practice34\x64\Debug\practice34.exe
```

> abort() has been called
> (Please Retry to debug the application)

I have options to either Abort, Retry or Ignore.

Retrying gives me this:
`C:\Users\..\source\repos\practice34\x64\Debug\practice34.exe` (process 9020) exited with code -2147483645.

Now I suppose, I should get a simple error in console using my string argument I passed in the error function. But instead I'm getting this. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: thats exactly what error is supposed to do. It is an assert. Visual studio is asking what you want to do next

Comment: The function does exactly what it says on the tin: "we supply an `error()` function that by default terminates the program with a system error message"

Comment: MSDN: [abort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/abort?view=msvc-170) "When the program is compiled in debug mode, the message box displays options to Abort, Retry, or Ignore. If the user chooses Abort, the program terminates immediately and returns an exit code of 3. If the user chooses Retry, a debugger is invoked for just-in-time debugging, if available. If the user chooses Ignore, abort continues normal processing."

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but I think it should display the string I passed inside the function call as an argument instead of instantly calling abort()

Comment: *but I think it should display the string* -- How are you writing this string?  If it's done using a buffer that isn't flushed, then it is a good chance your program aborted before the buffer was flushed, thus you don't see anything.